# Excel VBA - Append text to cell while keeping the cell's already changed text colors

Tags: vba, text, colors, append, cell

I'm running comparisions between data in two cells (ex. cell A1 & cell B1). I then add the results to a 'compared' cell.

- If something is added (new) in B1, I add that value to the 'compared' cell and color that value GREEN
- If something exists in both, I add    that value to the 'compared' cell and color that value BLACK
- If something exists in only A1 (removed in B1), I add that value to the 'compared' cell and color that value RED.

This works, but each time I add something new to the cell, the cell does not maintain the colors of the previously changed text.

I use the following to add the next item to the cell, and then color that item.

```
comparedCell.Value = comparedCell & "|" & myStringToAppend
comparedCell.Characters(Len(comparedCell) + 2, Len(myStringToAppend)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
```

Is there a way to add append colored text without resetting what I've already colored in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are testing the length of comparedCell *after* you have appended, so it will include the appended text.

Try using InStrRev() to find the last pipe character "|" entered and work from there.

Something like this:

```
comparedCell.Value = comparedcell & "|" & myStringToAppend
comparedCell.Characters(InStrRev(comparedCell, "|") + 1, Len(myStringToAppend)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
```

Comment: That improves my code, thank you. But it does not answer my question.

Comment: Actually it should help... I just have to rethink my logic a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure what the rest of your code is doing, but the snippet I posted will only change the colour of `myStringToAppend` after it has been added to `comparedCell` - is this not what you wanted? Maybe I misunderstood the question :(

Comment: Thats what the code currently does, the problem is that when I append new text to the cell, the previous things that I've appended and colored are reset to default color. I think I can go around this by adding things to 3 lists/arrays  (red/black/blue)  and then add those arrays to the cell. Afterwards, I can color the cell based on the number of items in each array. That way I can change the colors AFTER adding everything to the cell (preventing the colors from being overwritten). I'll probably count the number of "|" to find where the colors should change for the next array appended.